# Visited links are invisible on new profile

Tags: bug, design, user-profile

[image]

Some of these words are links! Can you tell which ones? I can't, because having visited them, their colour is almost identical to regular text.

Comment: I can, but I suspect it is monitor specific.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yeah I guess. They're completely invisible to me, I think my shiny screen 'enhances' dark colours, making them less distinguishable...

Comment: They look visible on my phone, I suspect it would be different on my actual monitor.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Either that or it's my special eyes.

Comment: This is happening to me too with my new screen. I changed the contrast and it seems better, however I cannot distinguish the links in the image above.

Comment: But when I look at you profile by clicking on the link of your name, the links are orange. Profile design update?

Comment: @angus main or meta? My problem is with main.

Comment: @fredley I can see unclicked links well, but clicked links are a bit harder to see. Still not as hard as the pic above.